# Join или union?

Tags: mysqli, sql

Одна таблица содержит текстовое поле и поле с id категории, которой этот текст соответствует. Вторая таблица содержит названия категорий и их id. По запросу, содержащему id категории, нужно вывести количество текстов этой категории и **название категории**.

Я не прошу предоставить мне код. Подскажите, что мне юзать - join или union?

Comment: а вы вообще понимаете разницу между join и union?

Comment: @DreamChild, давно когда-то использовал join при создании онлайн-чата. Забыл. Не помню. Что использовать в моем случае? У меня есть 2 часа в сутки для работы по веб. Времени нет. Подскажите, в каком направлении идти и достаточно.

Comment: приходите завтра :-/

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Я не прошу предоставить мне код. Подскажите, что мне юзать - join или union?

Comment: юзайте join.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov вчера - тоже вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN, т.к. UNION используется для объединения результатов различных запросов. У тебя есть связывающее поле ID, можно выбрать все ID из одной таблицы и расширить результат данными из другой через JOIN.